# Read Array of Hashes content

Tags: arrays, perl

I've pushed the results of my DBI query into the Array of Hashes and called a subroutine with these AoH's as an input (the same subroutine with different AoH's). As I don't know the exact size of my AoH, I'd like to determine it dynamically. Is there any way to get the number of fields/columns in the AoH?

Something like `scalar @inContent`, but I need the horizontal size only.

According to the actual size of AoH, I'd like to iterate it and read its content. At the moment I address fields by name, but it may vary from AoH to AoH, so it's not a very effective solution:

```
foreach my $row (@inContent) {
      print $row->{ID}; }
```

but would like to get something like that:

```
  print $row->[0]->value;
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It's a little confusing as to what you're actually asking here.  what is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The number of keys in the first hash in the array is

```
scalar keys %{$inContent[0]}
```

and the rest of them should have the same set of keys since it's a DBI query, so it's a good measure of "horizontal size".